# The case when n=1, or the case n=1

Tags: ellipsis, mathematics

In a mathematical proof (using the induction), when I deal with the base case, which is (if any) correct?

1. The case when n=1 is trivial
2. The case n=1 is trivial

I would like to know if I need "when" or not.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's unlikely that you're trying to prove n=1, "the case when n=1" is more likely to be appropriate.

Both are correct, but mean slightly different things. "The case n=1" means just that n=1, "the case when n=1" is referring to a broader equation or concept with n, and n is 1. For instance, you are trying to prove that the sum of the sum of the first *n* odd numbers is *n^2* and your base case is n=1.

Source: native speaker of English, studied college-level math

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by a broader equation. Could you give me examples that illustrate the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Since n=1 is a special case, it doesn't really need the 'when'. Adding the 'when' would be appropriate if you're jumping forwards, e.g. "the case when n=55 is interesting because..."